# предзагрузка данных в core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, coredata

здравствуйте.
возник вопрос: необходимо при ПЕРВОЙ загрузке приложения загрузить данные в core data, а затем их от туда вывести на экран. При этом при второй и последующих открытиях приложения, данные не загружать в core data, а сразу выводить их. И все это делается в автоматическом режиме (без каких либо кнопок и т.п.).

Как это реализовать?

Comment: Не понятно что у вас вызывает затруднения

Comment: в каком месте изменить код, чтобы при первой загрузке приложения выводились уже записанные заранее данные?

Comment: Если вы говорите "изменить", значит у вас есть код. Сложно сказать не видя его. Все зависит от архитектуры вашего приложения. Попробуйте задать вопрос конкретнее.

Comment: На пример, у меня приложение книга. Пользователь скачивает из аппстора и при первом открытии (без доступа в интернет) этого приложения сразу выдается текст на экран.

Comment: А в чем вопрос то? Загрузите эту книгу из файла. Попробуйте сформулировать вопрос заново, описав конкретную сложность.

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте при старте приложения пуста ли база  (сделайте выборку ваших сущностей - записей ), если логика приложения предполагает что в случае нулевой выборки базу надо проинициализировать начальным набором данных, ну так и инициализируйте ее в этом случае. Если выборка не пуста - выводите ее на UI.

Comment: вот этот вопрос меня и интересовал: какой командой сделать проверку?

Comment: это зависит от используемой базы и вашего кода

Answer (score 0):

Как вообще это должно работать.
В аппделегате вы создаете метод, в котором обьекты считываються из бд и записываються в массив. Если в массиве 0 элементов то мы добавляем в базу дефолтные обьекты, если больше нуля то просто запускаем приложение.

```
if (coredataOnjects.count == 0){
 //Добавляем обьекты в базу
}
```

Получаеться при запуске программы мы сотрим в базу и если не обнаруживаем записи, то добавляем их, а если все же находим то просто пропускаем добавление дефолтных объектов.